# Удаление данных с возможностью восстановления

Tags: ajax, php, javascript, mysql

Всем привет! Очень часто начал замечать на многих сайтах (сервисах) такую фичу, как удаление данных с помощью ajax, но с возможностью восстановить. То есть: Есть, например, личные сообщения, каждое сообщение разделено по отдельности и имеет Крестик (Для удаления сообщения), нажимаем удалить, сообщение исчезает и вместо место него написано что-то типа этого: "Сообщение удалено. <a>Восстановить</a>". И нажав кнопку восстановить, сообщение возвращается на место.

Я не могу разобраться в принципе работы этой функции. Получается, если мы удалим из базы при удалении, то уже восстановить не можем. Что и как используется?

Не могли вы бы поделиться принципом работы данной функции? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавляем в базу в таблицу сообщений поле OnDelete(по умолчанию = 0). 
При нажатии на крестик -> set OnDelete = 1 where IDMsg = n;

В модуле сообщений:

> if($onDelete = 1) $msg = 'Сообщение
> удалено. Восстановить';

Ну и соответственно по нажатию на восстановить -> set OnDelete = 0 where IDMsg = n;

Не вижу ничего сложного.

Так же можно на крон поставить скрипт который будет чистить базу:

> if($onDelete = 1 && $date-$dateNow < $timeToDelete) deleteMsgById(n);

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 4):

Это достаточно простая задача

1. каждое сообщение имеет поле удалено/не удалено по дефолту нет
2. при удалении оно не удаляется из базы, а просто ему выставляется метка - удалено
3. при выводе сообщений добавляется фильтр - только те у которых метка удаления не высталена
4. при этом самом ajax'е вы посылаете на сервер ID сообщения или любой другой уникальный идентификатор, скрипт получатель на сервере выставляет метку удаления сообщению и возвращает например кусок верстки с сообщением мол удалено восстановить
5. ссылка восстановить так же должна указывать ID удаленного сообщения а скрипт получатель просто менять метку на неудалено и возвращать что-то на ваще усмотрение..
6. после обновления страницы обычно сообщение об удаленном сообщении просто не выводится, но это уж дело вкусов и нравов.

Comment: А глянуть ответ под номером 1 сложно было?

Answer (score 3):

Что за функция использовалась там, где вы это видели, я не знаю, но ничего не мешает создать собственную. Например, есть таблица "basket_message", где есть поля: id-сообщения и поле со временем, которое будет оно еще храниться. Публике выводятся только те сообщения, id которых нет в данной таблице. Если юзер захотел восстановить, то удаляется запись из вышеуказанной таблицы. Если же время, отведенное на "жизнь" сообщению истекло, то оно удаляется и из этой таблицы, и из таблицы, где хранится его содержание автоматом.

Можно просто перемещать сообщения в отдельную таблицу, можно хранить только на время работы сессии и т.д. Тут вариантов столько, на сколько хватит вашей фантазии.